# How do I show custom WooCommerce Subscriptions data on the frontend for customers subscription details?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin to manage recurring orders.

But I want my customers to see custom data, that I add to all new subscriptions, on their subscriptions details page.

I add a variable for the customers baby name, which I add as `_baby_name` in the subscriptions data post_meta data like this:

```php
/**
 * Triggered after a new subscription is created.
 *
 * @since 2.2.22
 * @param WC_Subscription $subscription
 */
function action_wcs_create_subscription( $subscription ) {
    // Get ID
    $subscription_id = $subscription->get_id();

    update_post_meta( $subscription_id, '_baby_name', get_current_user_id() );
}
add_action( 'wcs_create_subscription', 'action_wcs_create_subscription', 10, 1 );
```

For testing purposes, I just set the value to be `get_current_user_id()`.

---

To present this custom data on the customers frontend, I have tried to modify the subscription-details.php file:

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-subscriptions/vendor/woocommerce/subscriptions-core/templates/myaccount/subscription-details.php

I added a row in the top of my subscription_details table, above the status row like this:

```php
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Baby Name', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo esc_html(  $subscription.'baby_name' ); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Status', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo esc_html( wcs_get_subscription_status_name( $subscription->get_status() ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
```

But in my new row for Baby Name, I just get all data associated with $subscriptions:

[image]

What should I use instead of `$subscription.'_baby_name'` to pull the value of `_baby_name`, and show it in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is saved as post meta, you can use `$subscription->get_meta( '_baby_name', true );`

So you get:

```php
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Baby Name', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $subscription->get_meta( '_baby_name', true ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Status', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo esc_html( wcs_get_subscription_status_name( $subscription->get_status() ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

OR use `get_post_meta( $subscription->get_id(), '_baby_name', true );`

```php
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Baby Name', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $subscription->get_id(), '_baby_name', true ); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php esc_html_e( 'Status', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' ); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo esc_html( wcs_get_subscription_status_name( $subscription->get_status() ) ); ?></td>
    </tr>
```

---

However, if you don't want to edit template files, you can use the `wcs_subscription_details_table_before_dates` action hook:

```php
function action_wcs_subscription_details_table_before_dates( $subscription ) {
    echo '<tr><td>'; 
    echo esc_html_e( 'Baby Name', 'woocommerce-subscriptions' );
    echo '</td><td>';
    echo get_post_meta( $subscription->get_id(), '_baby_name', true );
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
add_action( 'wcs_subscription_details_table_before_dates', 'action_wcs_subscription_details_table_before_dates', 10, 1 );
```

The only downside to this is that the new row will be displayed below the 'status' row, opposite above